# Measure Induced by Integral is Regular if Original Measure Regular

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove the following question:

> Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be measure space, $g$ positive measurable function. Then we have that $\nu := \int_{A}gd\mu$ is a positive measure on $\mathcal{A}$. Suppose $E$ is now locally compact and Hausdorff and that open sets of $E$ are $\sigma$- compact. Suppose also that $\mathcal{A}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\mu$ is a regular measure, and $g\in L^p(\mu)$ for some $p\in [1,\infty]$. Then show that $\nu$ is regular.

As for this question, my attempt is as follows, and yet I am not sure if it is correct.

Let $V$ be an open set, $V = \cup_{n\ge 1} H_n$, where $H_n$ are compact set. Then, let $H_1\prec f_1\prec V$. Denote $K_i$ as the support for $f_i$ and define $H_1\cup \dots\cup H_n \cup K_1 \cup\dots \cup H_n \prec f_{n+1}\prec V$. Then $(f_n)$ is increasing sequence and its limit is $\mathbb{1}_{V}$. Now, by monotone convergence, if q is the conjugate component of $p$ $$\nu(V) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n d\nu = \lim \int f_ng\ d\mu = \int g \mathbb{1}_V \ d\mu \leq \|g\|_p \left(\int \mathbb{1}_V \ d\mu\right)^{1/q} = \|g\|_p (\nu(V))^{1/q}$$

Now let $A\in \mathcal{A}$ be a Borel set, $\epsilon >0$, then by regularity of $\mu$, $\exists K$ compact, $V$ open s.t. $K\subset A \subset V$ and $\nu(V\setminus K) < \epsilon$. Note that compact sets are closed, so $V\setminus K$ is open, then $\nu(V\setminus K) \leq \|g\|_p (\nu(V\setminus K))^{1/q} < \|g\|_p \epsilon ^{1/q}$, and this gives the regularity of $\nu$.

I do realize that there may be flaws in this proof and I would really appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean:
$$
\int_{E} fd\nu = \int_{E} fg d\mu
$$ 
in (1)?

Comment: Oh yes you are right. Thank you!

Comment: Do you also mean to ask about $\nu$-integrability and $\mu$-integrability (not measurability) in (2)?

Comment: Yes, I am very sorry for the typo.

Comment: Instead of using the dominated convergence theorem, the monotone convergence theorem could be useful, since $s_n\nearrow f; s_ng\nearrow fg$

Comment: In my opinion, if you can't do the first, you shouldn't be working on the second.

Comment: I just finished the first, and do you mind giving a hint on the second?

Comment: Why do you use the fact that $\nu(V)$ is finite (that's only true if $g \in L^1$ or more generally when your $A$ has finite measure)? You also have an issue when $p=1$ so that the $\epsilon^{1/q}$ is actually $1$. Also, looking at the other comments, I fail to see two different questions...